# CodeIgniter Like and Where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a filter status and search, I am trying to make a query with this logic

If i have an input with both filter status and search

```
select * from table_name where status = 'Active' AND name like %search% or address like %search%
```

I want to search through the filtered record using status and vice versa, I want to status filter the searched records

I am trying to use this query but it seem not the right query

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_users');
$this->db->like('name', $string, "both");
$this->db->or_like('address', $string, "both");
$this->db->where('status', $status);
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: If you are in doubt, why not just use 

$this->db->query("YOUR QUERY"); 
 $result = $query->result(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify some groups:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_users')
    ->group_start()
        ->where('status', $status)
        ->or_group_start()
            ->like('name', $string, 'both')
            ->like('address', $string, 'both')
        ->group_end()
    ->group_end()
->get();
```

See https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: I've tried this but it says, Call to undefined method group_start()